# Signed Vs unsigned library with maven

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, jar

We are refactoring an old project to split the packages into smaller libraries. At the end, the libraries are loaded into a webstart application, so we need to sign the jars we are using.

All this works fine in theory, but since some of the classes remains in the "same" package, within different jars, I am getting issues with security certificates while running the unit tests within maven. Because I get signed code and unsigned code in the same package.

I was whishing to acheive this without moving the classes to avoid other projects to get broken.

What would be my options?

Comment: security certificates in your unit tests? Sounds wrong. Can you show the pom of your project. BTW: With smaller libraries you mean maven modules of a multi module build?

Comment: No, I mean completely separate projects. Pom dependency is managed like every other libraries.

Comment: Note that our libraries are deployed in maven signed.